# What kind of answer to accept if I posted a problem asking to check my answer and the problem was ultimately wrong?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Recently I posted a question [Four numbers are in AP such that the sum of numbers is $32$ and the greatest number is $3$ times the least. What is the product of the numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183707/876009) . In this I asked what was wrong in my approach and ultimately it was founded that the question was wrong. Before I go forward the line "The question was wrong" doesn't mean that website makes wrong question just it might be a typo mistake so there is no fault of that source. So now I received $2$ answers which answer the question however both the answers use the approach morely similarly to mine one in question which were right but not much helpful so which answer should I accept? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: It's entirely up to you which answer to accept, or whether to accept an answer at all. Pick the one you found more helpful; if they were equally helpful, flip a coin (but leave a nice note on the other one); if neither was helpful, fuggedaboudid.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what if both were not helpful but the question is fully solved because some people in comment wrote wrong question?

Comment: It's up to you. It's up to you. It's up to you. If the question is fully solved, write up the solution, post it as an answer, and give credit to the commenters who solved it or helped you solve it.

Comment: Okay thanks @GerryMyerson. If you can write it as a answer I will accept it. If you can't create a answer then I will delete my question once taking advice from my members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converted from comment, at request of OP:]

It's up to you. If the question is fully solved, write up the solution, post it as an answer, and give credit to the commenters who solved it or helped you solve it.